# numpy histogram indexing

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

considering I have a 3D histogram or for simplicity a 3D numpy array of shape (X,Y,Z)

```
import numpy as np
array = np.random.random((100,100,100))
```

What is the best way, using numpy or scipy to obtain array's values' indexes of which satisfy a sphere conditions?

```
(index_x**2 + index_y**2 + index_z**2) <= radius**2
```

Obvioulsy, in the later condition, the array center is (0, 0, 0). In general the condition will be

```
((index_x-center_x)**2 + (index_y-center_y)**2 +(index_z-center_z)**2) <= radius**2
```

The problem is easy to solve using simply a python loop, but I need that to be optimized.

many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for making @EOL nice approach more general, one can define a center within the shape of the array

```
array = np.random.random((100,100,100))
center = (30,10,25)
radius = 5.0
x, y, z = np.ogrid[-center[0]:array.shape[0]-center[0],-center[1] :array.shape[1]-center[1], -center[2]:array.shape[2]-center[2]]
indexes = numpy.transpose((x**2+y**2+z**2 <= radius**2).nonzero())
```

Answer (score 4):

You can first efficiently get the indexes with `ogrid()` and then obtain the indexes that satisfy your condition with `nonzero()`.

Getting the indexes can be obtained with [nonzero](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero)() like so:

```
indexes = numpy.transpose((x**2+y**2+z**2 <= radius**2).nonzero())  # transpose() might be unnecessary: it depends on your needs
```

where the indexes arrays are obtained efficiently with [ogrid](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html)():

```
x, y, z = numpy.ogrid[:100, :100, :100]
```

or, for an arbitrary shape for your input `data` array:

```
x, y, z = ogrid[tuple(slice(None, dim) for dim in data.shape)]
```

Comment: fantastic ... I thought of using ogrid but didn't know it works in multi-dimensions
thank you very much